# Observable TakeUntil with Multiple Conditions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

What's the best way to add multiple conditions to TakeUntil?  Is it just a matter of chaining TakeUntil() calls to each other?

```
IObservable<MyClass> propertyToObserve = ...
var observable = propertyToObserve
    .TakeUntil(SomeCondition)
    .TakeUntil(OtherCondition)
    .Subscribe(value => ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a reasonable way to do it. Another way is to merge the conditions:

```
source.TakeUntil(condition1.Merge(condition2))
.Subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Agreed. (a * b) * c = a * (b * c). This is more a question about style than anything else.

Comment: Should we use `this.destroy$.next()` and `this.destroy$.complete()` in `ngOnDestroy()` when using `takeUntil`?

Comment: @Fredrick this Q has nothing to do with JavaScript or Angular.  Perhaps you should pose a new question